# Gravity-forms How to dynamically pass the total of the two fields as a dynamic value to the third field

Tags: gravity-forms-plugin

I have a form with a quantity field which I want to dynamically populate with the total of the values from the text input field that the user enters.

Want to know if this is achievable in gravity-forms... I can't really find any reference to this.

So as the user enters a numeric value in the text fields, before the form submission I want to calculate the sum of those numbers and display it as a total quantity. 
I have set the quantity field to populate dynamically but don't know how to retrieve the user input and pass it to quantity field.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I figured it out, posting the working solution which might help someone.

Comment: Do you still have the working solution?